# How to remove specific data along with the angle brackets

Tags: regex, outsystems

I need to remove a specific data from xml file along with data, I tried lot but couldn't get the right approach. Please help me out.

Example Input:

```
<isOurAccount>false</isOurAccount><maturityDate/><openedDate/><valuationAmount>0<valuationAmount><value>0</value>
```

Expected output:

```
<isOurAccount>false</isOurAccount><valuationAmount>0<valuationAmount><value>0</value>
```

Similarly for rest of the elements for pattern `<somevalue/>`

Couldn't get the specific regular expression.

Thanks

Comment: use an xml parser. add a tag for the language or tool you are using.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do with regex .. as it would be easily integrated with outsystems..

Comment: Why not a simple find `<maturityDate\s*/>|<openedDate\s*/>`, replace `""`

Comment: http://www.outsystems.com/forge/component_details.aspx?ProjectId=55

Comment: @Akhilesh did the answer work for you? could you accept it if so? thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple RegEx replace action to substitute with empty "" all occurrences of `<[a-zA-Z]+ *\/>` should suffice.

*RegEx description retrieved from [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com_)*

> `<` matches the characters `<` literally
>
> `[a-zA-Z]+` match a single character present in the list below
>
> Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>
> `a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
>
> `A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
>
> `(space)*` matches the space character literally
>
> Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>
> `\/` matches the escaped character `/` literally
>
> `>` matches the characters `>` literally